# How to correctly specify a common name for Service Fabric certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric

Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-change-cert-thumbprint-to-cn#get-a-certificate) say to use something like `clustername.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`, but what about custom DNS for the cluster?

Will the certificate properly validate or should the custom DNS (i.e. clustername.domain.com) be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dns provided by the docs is just an example, I don't think you will be able to register a certificate against a domain you don't own like `.azure.com`.

In this case, you will register a certificate against a domain you own, and you either:

- Register a CNAME record on your damain to redirect to the cluster domain `clustername.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` or
- Configure the DNS A Record to point to you cluster Load Balancer IP

In the demo, the Commom Name is just used to identify the certificate installed in the node(vm) certificate store.

The following links describes the use of certificates in more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-windows-cluster-x509-security

Comment: Thanks, Diego! The subject of my existing cert has a CN of clustername.domain.com, so based on that and the docs, I should be all set. Unless I'm missing something else?

Comment: Yes, as far I remember should be all you need

Comment: Is it possible to use a wildcard certificate?